# How to attach user data to hockey app crash log (HockeySDK for Unity / Android)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hockeyapp

I am using (HockeySDK for Unity / Android) in my game and i want to add user id to crash log, so i can filter crash logs by user_string in hockey app.

For that i derived from HockeyAppAndroid and override method GetLogHeaders

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tools.HockeyApp
{
    public class EvoHockeyAppAndroid : HockeyAppAndroid
    {
        protected override List<string> GetLogHeaders()
        {
            var headers = base.GetLogHeaders();

            uid = "User: " + HockeyAppUtils.GetUID();
            headers.Add(uid);

            return headers;
        }
    }
}
```

As result i getting crashlog like that.User from ash log dosent appeared in Meta as Device or OS Version
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do this, you need to recreate the following query

curl \
  - F " log=@crash.log" \
  - F " description=@description.txt" \
  - F " attachment0=@some.dat" \
  - F "userID=1234567890" \
  - F "contact=thomas@dohmke.de" \
  https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef/crashes/upload